# Show the mean values of column X by the first letter of column Y. Confusing results

Tags: r

I'm trying to get the mean values of a column based on the first letter of another column.

Here is what is happening:
[image]

The first solution gives me incorrect results, and the second says that the column isn't numeric, which it is:

[image]

The results are the same with na.rm=TRUE.

```
Dput: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/07ab0327708fefc37c3d42fc8fed569220200910222609/e80741

Dput: structure(list(ID = c(9471292, 10304260, 10689471, 10497936, 
9863005, 9274420), date = structure(c(16093, 16746, 17065, 16916, 
16393, 15939), class = "Date"), time = new("Period", .Data = c(-23, 
-7, -21, -25, -19, -22), year = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), month = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), day = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), hour = c(2014, 2015, 
2016, 2016, 2014, 2013), minute = c(-1, -11, -9, -4, -11, -8)), 
    `Primary Type` = c("MOTOR VEHICLE THEFT", "THEFT", "BATTERY", 
    "BATTERY", "THEFT", "CRIMINAL DAMAGE"), Description = c("AUTOMOBILE", 
    "OVER $500", "DOMESTIC BATTERY SIMPLE", "DOMESTIC BATTERY SIMPLE", 
    "RETAIL THEFT", "TO VEHICLE"), `Location Description` = c("STREET", 
    "SIDEWALK", "RESIDENCE", "RESIDENCE", "SMALL RETAIL STORE", 
    "CHA PARKING LOT/GROUNDS"), Arrest = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, TRUE), Domestic = c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, 
    FALSE, FALSE), Beat = c(433, 1022, 324, 822, 412, 915), District = c(4, 
    10, 3, 8, 4, 9), Ward = c(10, 24, 8, 23, 8, 3), `Community Area` = c(52, 
    29, 43, 62, 48, 34), newcol = structure(c(5L, 7L, 4L, 2L, 
    4L, 5L), .Label = c("Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", 
    "Sat"), class = c("ordered", "factor"))), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Try `df1 %>% group_by(grp = substr(Y, 1, 1)) %>% summmarise(X = mean(X, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% slice_max(X) %>% pull(grp)`

Comment: I'm getting "Warning message:
In mean.default("X", na.rm = TRUE) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA"

Comment: `mean` works with numeric values. Please check the `str(df1)` and if it is not numeric convert to numeric with `df1$X <- as.numeric(as.character(df1$X))` in case it is `factor`

Comment: I've added a lot more details. Please recheck the post

Comment: INside the tidyverse, you don't need `Chicago$` and in the second case, you may need `mean(`Community Area`, na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: Fair enough. But i get the same results anyways.

Comment: I used `na.rm = TRUE` which I don't see in the image

Comment: "The results are the same with na.rm=TRUE"

Comment: Image shows the column as `numeric`.  Can you update the post with  dput of small example to test

Comment: I uploaded the dput file.

Comment: Can you show it in your post rather than a link to external url.  Or upload in github because the url is asking to allow for cookies etc.

Comment: I'll add the code given by dput(chicago)

Comment: I am getting the correct output

Comment: Can you rerun on a fresh R session with only `dplyr` and `stringr` loaded.  What is the `dplyr` version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We get the `substr`ing of the 'Primary Type' column as a grouping column, then `summarise` by taking the `mean` of 'Community Area'

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
chicago %>% 
    group_by(Letters = str_sub(`Primary Type`, 1, 1))  %>%
    summarise(Mean = mean(`Community Area`, na.rm = TRUE))
#A tibble: 4 x 2
#  Letters  Mean
#  <chr>   <dbl>
#1 B        52.5
#2 C        34  
#3 M        52  
#4 T        38.5
```

NOTE: If there are spaces or other unusual characters in column names, use backquotes to evaluate

Comment: Removing the blank spaces in str_sub('Primary Type', 1, 1) literally breaks the input.....what the hell. Try "chicago %>% 
+     group_by(Letters = str_sub(`Primary Type`,1,1)) %>%
+     summarise(Mean = mean('Community Area', na.rm = TRUE))" . Its literally the same code without the spaces and it wont work.

Comment: @Hristmar if there are spaces in column names, it should be back quoted to evaluate or use `.data[["Primary Type"]]`

Comment: This is by far the weirdest problem i've had while programming. Thank you for your help.